# how to show flash massage Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want a show a flash message in my login page user register and
redirect back with success message to login page how to show flash message in a login page

this is the function **RegisterController.php**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->withMessage('message', 'my msg');        

}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
 @if (session('message'))
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
   {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: pls go through laravel official documentation first before posting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `withMessage('message', 'my msg')` you already gave the key to your message. So either use just `withMessage('my msg')` or `->with('message', 'my msg')`.

And noticing the other answers using the `flash` separately, but `with` already uses `flash` session.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Session::flash('message', 'Your message!');` to your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your controller like this:

```
return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('message', ['my msg']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try bellow code:

In controller:

```
use Session;
Session::flash('success','Success Message.');
Session::flash('danger','Error Message.');
Session::flash('warning','Warning Message.');
Session::flash('info','Info Message.');
```

In blade file:

```
@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
        <p class="success text-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```